# How to do navigation.setOptions in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm setting up stack navigation using typescript and it's my first time working with typescript. I have a screen `Login.tsx` in which I want to customize the navigation bar.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../typings';

type loginScreenProps = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Login'>;

const Login = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation<loginScreenProps>();

  navigation.setOptions  = {
    headerTitle: 'Demo', // <-- ERROR
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Login</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default Login
```

The error I'm going is:

> Type '{ headerTitle: string; }' is not assignable to type '(options:
> Partial) => void'.   Object literal may only
> specify known properties, and 'headerTitle' does not exist in type
> '(options: Partial) => void'.

The `RootStackParamList` is simple `expor type RootStackParamList = { Login: undefined;...`

How do I achieve it in typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**navigation.setOptions is a function** which takes object as an input

Try making this change and let me know if its fixed

```
navigation.setOptions({
  headerTitle: 'Demo',
})
```

Comment: Doing so made it work but there is a warning `Warning: Cannot update a component (`StackNavigator`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`,` any improvements to your answer that can make it go away? I put it in a `useEffect` and that made the warning go away, but not sure of that it is the right solution.

Comment: try to execute it in useEffect because setOptions will call with every state update.

useEffect(()=>{
navigation.setOptions({
  headerTitle: 'Demo',
})
}, [false]);